# Stop PKWare from zipping attachments

Tags: zip, attachments

Recently I installed PKWare SecureZip on my machine and incredibly annoying it is zipping all my attachments and I can't figure out how to make it stop. The PKWare Help is useless.

Comment: You should be able to prevent that by disabling the pkware outlook add-on

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is that I had to go to Install/Uninstall Programs, select the PkWare Application, then re-run the installer. At one point the installer lists the installation options. I had to unselect the "mail integration" option. Then continue through the "installation" process. When it was finished, the PkWare addin was gone from Outlook.